# For DHT, what's the advantage of a 160-bit key over 128-bit?

Tags: algorithm, dht

Wikipedia tells me that distributed hash tables (DHT) normally use either a 128-bit or a 160-bit keyspace.

128 bits is huge.  1.7 x 10^28.
160 bits is bigger.  7.3 x 10^47, roughly the number of atoms on/in the planet.
(256 bits gets you to order-of the number of atoms in existence.)

What would you store in a hashtable where 10^28 was too small of a keyspace?  Did they just go one step larger because they could?

Comment: Have a look at the birthday paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem. The probability of collisions is much higher than one would think.

Comment: @Henry, according to the table in that article, you would need to have 2.2 x 10^19 items in a hash table with a 128 bit keyspace before you had a 50% chance of a collision. Even if you're only prepared to tolerate a 1 in 10^6 chance, you'd still need to insert 2.6 x 10^16 items to reach that threshold. That's an enormous number.

Comment: SHA1 gives you 160 bits, that gives you an excuse to use 160 bit keys without having to go into technical reasons

Comment: For the birthday paradox, it just doesn't matter that much; buckets in hashtables expecting overlap can use trees for storage.  Are 160-bit keyed DHT using open addressing?

Comment: SHA1... okay, *that* makes a lotta sense.  It also wouldn't make much sense to jump to SHA-256, as that's silly big if you've already got a smaller tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically sha1 has been used for value -> key mappings, hence 160bits.

But larger sizes may make sense for DHTs that employ elliptic curve cryptography with the public key being identical to the node IDs or requiring more than 80bits of collision resistance.

Smaller sizes on the other hand only make sense if you need to squeeze out every byte and don't care much for security (i.e. you're not attached to the internet).